# htaccess not working for subfolders

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, hyperlink, url-rewriting, subdirectory

i want to ask why my .htaccess in root folder does not work well.

.htaccess

```
RewriteEngine On 
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9]+)(/[a-zA-Z0-9/]+)?$ /$1\.php$2 [L]

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^GET\s/*pages/.*\.php [NC] 
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9]+)(/[a-zA-Z0-9/]+)?$ /$1\.php$2 [L]

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^GET\s/*debates/.*\.php [NC]
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9]+)(/[a-zA-Z0-9/]+)?$ /$1\.php$2 [L]
```

Links in the / (main folder) are with working .php hidding, but in the subfolders like /pages/ and /debates/ the system does not recognize rewrite rule. I want to hide .php in both directories like they are hidden in the main folder.

I FIND THE SOLUTION!

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.+)$ $1.php [L,QSA]
```

Comment: I think you'd need to check if file exists or not using `!-f`.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like these rules are all wrong, they wouldn't do anything:

```
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^GET\s/*pages/.*\.php [NC] 
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9]+)(/[a-zA-Z0-9/]+)?$ /$1\.php$2 [L]

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^GET\s/*debates/.*\.php [NC]
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9]+)(/[a-zA-Z0-9/]+)?$ /$1\.php$2 [L]
```

You could just change your htaccess to this:

```
RewriteEngine On 
RewriteRule ^pages/([a-zA-Z0-9]+)(/[a-zA-Z0-9/]+)?$ /pages/$1\.php$2 [L]
RewriteRule ^debates/([a-zA-Z0-9]+)(/[a-zA-Z0-9/]+)?$ /debates/$1\.php$2 [L]
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9]+)(/[a-zA-Z0-9/]+)?$ /$1\.php$2 [L]
```

Comment: The requested URL /9e6c561c1f.php was not found on this server.

Additionally, a 404 Not Found error was encountered while trying to use an ErrorDocument to handle the request.

The file EXISTS! When i change the extension from blank to +.php in the url bar it opens.